# Always get a RowExclusiveLock on table pg_proc When I create a Function,why?

Tags: database, postgresql, function

Below is the create function code:

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION "public".createtable_if_not_exists(schema_name1 text, table_name text,create_stmt text)
RETURNS text AS
$_$
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(select tablename from pg_catalog.pg_tables where schemaname = schema_name1 AND tablename = table_name) THEN
        RETURN 'Already exists';
    ELSE
        EXECUTE create_stmt;
        RETURN 'Created';
    END IF;
END;
$_$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Any idea?

A reason to explain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pg_proc` is the system catalog where functions are stored. When you create a function, a row is inserted into `pg_proc`. Whenever you `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` rows in a table, the table is locked in `ROW EXCLUSIVE` mode (to prevent incompatible concurrent statements like `DROP TABLE` or `CREATE INDEX`). This is the same for system catalog tables and normal tables.

Comment: So basically I should do  #vacuum full pg_catalog.pg_proc?
Anything else i should try?

Comment: No, you don't have to do that. Autovacuum does it when necessary. There is nothing special to consider; the same happens on the corresponding metadata table when you create any object.

Comment: Sorry,Autovacuum not enabled. so i #vacuum full the whole pg_catalog schema..
and Problem solved!, Thanks!

Comment: You'll still get the lock on the catalog when you create a function. `VACUUM (FULL)` is quite unrelated to that. But maybe your question as asked doesn't describe your actual problem (because the `ROW EXCLUSIVE` lock on a catalob cannot be a problem).

Comment: I guess i get a very long time of RowExclusiveLock before #vacuum full,
after  the #vacuum full ,the Lock turns into a few milliseconds.

Comment: `CREATE FUNCTION` is always very short. Well, your problem remains undescribed and mysterious. Let's let it rest.

Comment: Let`s consider an environment where Postgresql 11 runs with many heavy Load applicatioins on Windows 10. Anything can happen ...